# Angular2 seed project aot compilation no ngfactory files generated

Tags: angular, aot, angular2-aot

I have created an angular2 aot seed project based on the official tutorials, but ngc compilation does not generate ngfactory files.

Could you help me what can be the reason?

Project site: https://github.com/petermezei/angular2-aot-webpack-website-seed

The project is very very minimal just to check what can be wrong.

Ngc command I used: `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json`

Thank you in advance,
Peter Mezei.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098430/angular-aot-app-folder-is-not-generated